# File exist but console says it does not exist

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a project which it's structure it's based on the [pitftmenu](https://github.com/garthvh/pitftmenu).
I have created mine and by calling each py file separately everything looks to work smoothly.
If you notice on the pitftmenu there is a menu file which kind of links each py file (menu) together and you can switch to one another.
I have created mine according to my needs but when I call sudo ./menu on the console, the console says it does not exist.
It used to work but, I was experimenting with something else on my raspberry Pi, and I had to reinstall rasbian. I moved back my files and installed "all the packages" I needed. My only issue is that and I dont know why.
It is worth to be mentioned that if I run the menu file on the pitftmenu folder it is working. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try chmod 777 ?

Comment: It's not executable. If it should be, mark it as such with `chmod a+x menu`

Comment: Thanks spectras. Thats it!

Comment: @JoséCarlos That's poor advice, as it will make the file writable for all users.

Comment: I was just asking, To be fair, I didn't mean he should do that. I just wanted to discard that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spectras said - It's not executable. If it should be, mark it as such with `chmod a+x menu`

Credits to spectras for the solution